# If dict2 value = dict1 key, replace entire dict2 value with dict1 value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, replace

I have two dictionaries. In both dictionaries, the value of each key is a single list. If any element in any list in dictionary 2 is equal to a key of dictionary 1, I want to replace that element with the first element in that dictionary 1 list.

In other words, I have:

```
dict1 = {'IDa':['newA', 'x'], 'IDb':['newB', 'x']}
dict2 = {1:['IDa', 'IDb']}
```

and I want:

```
dict2 = {1:['newA', 'newB']}
```

I tried:

```
for ID1, news in dict1.items():
    for x, ID2s in dict2.items():
        for ID in ID2s:
            if ID == ID1:
                print ID1, 'match'
                ID.replace(ID, news[0])

for k, v in dict2.items():
    print k, v
```

and I got:

```
IDb match
IDa match
1 ['IDa', IDb']
```

So it looks like everything up to the replace method is working. Is there a way to make this work? To replace an entire string in a value-list with a string in another value-list?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dict1 = {'IDa':['newA', 'x'], 'IDb':['newB', 'x']}
dict2 = {1:['IDa', 'IDb']}

for key in dict2.keys():
    dict2[key] = [dict1[x][0] if x in dict1.keys() else x for x in dict2[key]]

print dict2
```

this will print:

```
{1: ['newA', 'newB']}
```

as required.

### Explanation

`dict.keys()` gives us just the keys of a dictionary (i.e. just the left hand side of the colon). When we use `for key in dict2.keys()`, at present our only key is `1`. If the dictionary was larger, it'd loop through all keys.

The following line uses a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) - we know that `dict2[key]` gives us a list (the right side of the colon), so we loop through every element of the list (`for x in dict2[key]`) and return the first entry of the corresponding list in `dict1` **only if** we can find the element in the keys of `dict1` (`dict1[x][0] if x in dict1.keys`) and otherwise leave the element untouched (`[else x]`).

For example, if we changed our dictionaries to be the following:

```
dict1 = {'IDa':['newA', 'x'], 'IDb':['newB', 'x']}
dict2 = {1:['IDa', 'IDb'], 2:{'IDb', 'IDc'}}
```

we'd get the output:

```
{1: ['newA', 'newB'], 2: ['newB', 'IDc']}
```

because `'IDc'` doesn't exist in the keys of `dict1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What can I search to read more about the structure of that code?

Comment: @ddrsee you're welcome! I edited the answer to provide a bit more detail, hope this helps.

Comment: You're the best. Can't thank you enough for your answer and taking the time to explain the process. I need to become familiar with list comprehensions. Cheers.

Comment: @ddrsee no worries, list comprehensions (and dictionary comprehensions) are really handy methods for creating lists (and dictionaries). In fact, we could replace our entire for loop with a one-line statement as seen in Guillaume's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use dictionary comprehensions, but I am not sure that they are working in Python 2.7, it may be limited to Python 3 :

```
# Python 3
dict2 = {k: [dict1.get(e, [e])[0] for e in v] for k,v in dict2.items()}
```

edit: I just checked, this is working in Python 2.7. However, dict2.items() should be replaced by dict2.iteritems() :

```
# Python 2.7
dict2 = {k: [dict1.get(e, [e])[0] for e in v] for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}
```

Comment: I tried it with `.items` in Python 2.7 and it worked okay for me. +1 for the neat one-liner.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and thanks for checking if it works in Python 2.7. I will use this when I start learning about dictionary comprehensions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun one!

```
dict2[1] = [dict1[val][0] if val in dict1 else val for val in dict2[1]]
```

Or, here is the same logic without list comprehension:

```
new_dict = {1: []}

for val in dict2[1]:
    if val in dict1:
        new_dict[1].append(dict1[val][0])
    else:
        new_dict[1].append(val)

dict2 = new_dict
```